# Deny requests after repeated request for a short period of time

Tags: php

I have a download counter on my site, and I want to stop spammers from incrementing the counter to absurd numbers, so, whenever someone downloads something, I want to add something like a timer, that if the user tries to download again before the timer ends it won't increment. I have tried using `$_SESSION` but I haven't gotten this to work and even if I did, it wouldn't matter as using something without cookies would probably go around this measure. My other idea is to add a log of IPs alongside the last time they downloaded, and if this time is older than some minutes it will increase the counter, but this solution would just require adding dumb fields to a database. Is there a better way or is this my best bet?

Comment: i think you are looking for rate-limiting you can find a tutorial for [rate limiting](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-php-rate-limiting-with-redis-on-ubuntu-20-04). You can google it for more information

Comment: right, ratelimiting is the word, i had forgotten haha, i'll search.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.